# Error building Meteor ios app with local package

Tags: cordova, meteor, isobuild

I've forked the [zeroasterisk BGgeolocation plugin](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/meteor-cordova-geolocation-background) to fix a bug (well, a change of object structure) which I think was introduced in iOS8. My fork is [here](https://github.com/FickleLife/meteor-cordova-geolocation-background) and is set up as a local package on my development server. I can add `meteor add ficklelife:cordova-geolocation-background` as it's in my local package path with no problems, however when I try to build an iOS app I get:

```
meteor build ../build/bgloctest --server http://<server address>.onmodulus.net:80
=> Errors while initializing project:         

While selecting package versions:
error: unknown package: ficklelife:cordova-geolocation-background
```

Googling around yields nothing - any clues why I can't compile with a local package? Possibly there is a path variable I have to set specifically for cordova/isobuild to work?

Comment: did you give a try to [this](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:geolocation)?

Comment: Unfortunately that's for user location within a browser - I want to track user location via a Cordova App when it has been backgrounded.

Comment: So if you do `meteor run ios` in the same directory, it runs correctly and loads your plugin?